# proof using field axioms only

Tags: field-theory

I am studying the field axioms for real numbers from the book 'Tom m Apostol Calculus' and i am wondering if the following can be proved using the field axioms only. a=a and b=(b).

the proofs that i have attempted are as follows

a+0=0+a    ( associative law)
a=0+a but '0+a' is not stated as a.

the proof for
(a+0)+0= a+(0+0) [ commutative law]
(a)+0=a+(0)
but (0) need not be equal to 0.

Comment: I think you have some misunderstanding with brakets notation. The symbols $x$ and $(x)$ denote the same thing.

Comment: Hey thanks for answering.But if what you are saying is true then why is 'x=(x)'not stated as an axiom in the book.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an axiom of field, since it's just a matter of notation. It's a rule of brackets that $(x)=x$.

In fact addition is a binary operation on your field $K$, defined as a map $+: K \times K \longrightarrow K$ with $(a,b) \mapsto +(a,b)$ satisfying some axioms.

The axiom $a+0 = 0+a = a$ is rewritten as $+(a,0) = +(0,a) = a$.

So, for example,
$$a+(0+0) = +(a, +(0,0)) = +(a, 0) = a$$